# how to get ip from domain in php?

Tags: php, ip, ping

(**I exexute my code in DOS**) this is my code:

```
<?php
$handle = fopen("domann.txt", "r");
if ($handle) {
    while (($line = fgets($handle)) !== false) {
        $ip = gethostbyname($line);
        echo "reading: ".$line. " ip: ".$ip  ;
    }

    fclose($handle);
} else {
    // error opening the file.
}

?>
```

I'd like to have something  like this:

reading: www.abc.it ip: 211.195.239.122

**the problem is not in  gethostbyname() function!!
it must be something in the  fgets($handle) that return also a \n for each line read**

**here the solution:**

```
$handle = fopen("file.txt", "r");
if ($handle) {
    while (($line = fgets($handle)) !== false) {

      $line=str_replace("\r\n","",$line);
        $ip = gethostbyname($line);

      echo "reading: ".$line." ip: ".$ip;
      echo "\n";
    }

    fclose($handle);
} else {
    echo "connection error";
}
```

Comment: What's the problem with the code you shared? Errors?

Comment: That should work. Perhaps do a ```var_dump``` on ```$line``` and see what it is

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php

Comment: and the contents of `domann.txt` is unknown and its formatting.

Comment: I've obviously have fallen onto deaf ears, once again. Oh that's not just me neither. Did you walk away to school or something?

Comment: the content of my txt file is a list of domain like:
www.google.com
www.yahoo.com

Comment: you need to paste your text file in an edit and **exactly** as what the contents are. Seeing that the question is still unsolved and comments keep piling up, is taking more time than it should. You mention `\n` being shown and that part is perplexing. and how are you executing this as, `file:///file.php` or `http://localhost/file.php`?

Comment: run this from a website and you'll see it's going to work. Working from command line will give you different and unexpected results. You should have told us from the beginning.

Answer (score 1):

Hey there @Luca i've found out why your code i'snt working, its because in your domann.txt probably you have named website likes **http://google.com** or **http://www.google.com** which doesnt work, the only way that works in **www.google.com**  so in your domann.txt name your website urls like www. suffix and nothing more this should fix it . For a proof [image: Works Fine]

Comment: You may have something there. I asked the OP 10 minutes as to what the content of their text file is, no response. [As per this comment...](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38831966/how-to-get-ip-from-domain-in-php#comment65029507_38831966).

Comment: Yes this is a bad practise, ppl asking questions and not looking for answers i agree @Fred-ii-  , I am too waiting for him

Comment: just give me a moment!  the file contain a list of domain like www.google.com, one for each line.

Comment: if I write gethostbyname("www.google.it");  it works fine but if i write gethostbyname($line); like in my example the output I get is this: 
reading: www.google.it
ip:  www.google.it

Comment: try to echo ur $line before sending it into the gethostbyname and see what it shows , and then lets see

Comment: I already try to display the lines with echo.. maybe when I read the line I also get the \n  which i can't see in echo ?

Comment: this is what I'm trying to do XD... p.s.  I execute my php from windows DOS by command line is this make any  difference?

Comment: nah doesnt make any difference with it

Comment: @StackB00m those `\n` are coming from the command line because of the "invisible" returns on each line in the file.

Answer (score 0):

try this,

http://php.net/gethostbyname

```
$names = file('domann.txt');
 foreach ($names as $name) {
     $ip = gethostbyname($name);
     echo  $ip.' <br>';
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

**here the solution:**

```
$handle = fopen("file.txt", "r");
if ($handle) {
    while (($line = fgets($handle)) !== false) {

      $line=str_replace("\r\n","",$line);
        $ip = gethostbyname($line);

      echo "reading: ".$line." ip: ".$ip;
      echo "\n";
    }

    fclose($handle);
} else {
    echo "connection error";
}
```